# Client side Ajax call on CORS server doesn't include credentials

Tags: java, ajax, tomcat, cors, shiro

I'm using Shiro in my web app for security over the REST API. It works fine when the client side is running on the same server, but I can't get it to work with CORS requests. After some research, the app looks like that:

web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.company.project.cors.CORSFilter</filter-class>
    <!--<filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>-->
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/v2/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

I tried with the tomcat's CorsFilter implementations, but as I couldn't get it to work, I implemented my own custom filter:

```
public class CORSFilter implements Filter {

    public CORSFilter() {}

    public void destroy() {}

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
        System.out.println("CORSFilter HTTP Request: " + request.getMethod());

        HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;

        String origin = request.getHeader("Origin");
        resp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin);
        resp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
        resp.setHeader("Vary", "Origin");
        resp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        resp.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "6000");
        resp.setHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers","Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Access-Control-Allow-Credentials, Access-Control-Allow-Methods");

    if (request.getMethod().equals("OPTIONS")) {
        resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_ACCEPTED);
        resp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "PUT, GET, OPTIONS, POST, DELETE");
        return;
    }

        // pass the request along the filter chain
        chain.doFilter(request, servletResponse);
    }

    public void init(FilterConfig fConfig) throws ServletException {}
}
```

I modified a service to check what the server was receiving in CORS requests:

```
    @POST
    @Compress
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getElementsSearch(SearchRequestObject sro, @Context HttpServletRequest hsr) {
        Subject currentUser = SecurityUtils.getSubject();
        System.out.println("Current User: " + currentUser);
        System.out.println("Session: " + currentUser.getSession(false));
        System.out.println("Current User: " + currentUser.getPrincipal());
        System.out.println("Origin: " + hsr.getHeader("Origin"));
        System.out.println("Headers: ");
        Enumeration<String> e1 = hsr.getHeaderNames();
        while(e1.hasMoreElements()) {
            String param = e1.nextElement();
            System.out.print(param + "; ");
        }
        System.out.println("Cookie: " + hsr.getHeader("cookie"));   

        if(!currentUser.isAuthenticated())  
            return Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED).build();
         .
         .
         .
}
```

The ajax call using jQuery looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url:  ServerUrl+'search',
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(objSearch),
    headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'},
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },
    success: function (result) {
        //Format result

    }, //success
    error: ajaxErrorCallback
});
```

This call returns `unauthorized` because the cookie with the `JSESSIONID` isn't include in the request's headers in spite of having set the `xhrFields.withCredentials` to true, so the server treat it like a new not-authenticated session. I don't know whether the problem is in the server or client side. Does anyone knows if I missed something?

Answer (score 0):

The login request must include the `withCredentials=true` flag too. If not, it seems like the JSESSIONID cookie is dismissed by the browser. Now it's working fine.